# update statement with join and dynamic table name

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to update one table from another when the updating table name is a variable.

```
DECLARE @TableName Varchar(100) 
DECLARE @Query Varchar(MAX)

DECLARE @Month  Varchar(100) 
SELECT @Month=9

DECLARE @Year  Varchar(100) 
SELECT @Year=2020

SELECT @TableName=CONCAT('Tbl_Billing_Sheet_', @Month , '_',  @Year)

SET @Query = 'UPDATE
    '+@TableName+'
SET
    @TableName.[1] = RAN.[1]
FROM
   '+ @TableName +'SI
INNER JOIN
    Stg_Billing_Sheet RAN
ON 
    SI.Associate_ID = RAN.Associate_ID'

    EXEC (@query)
```

Comment: Seems like the real problem is the design. `Month` and `Year` should be columns in a table called `Tbl_Billing_Sheet`, not suffixes of the name of table named `Tbl_Billing_Sheet_9_2020`. Fix the design, fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so close! You have one of your @TableName variables stuck inside a string literal--where the table name isn't even necessary I believe.

Try the following:

```
DECLARE 
    @TableName Varchar(100), 
    @Query Varchar(MAX), 
    @Month VARCHAR(100), 
    @Year VARCHAR(100);

SELECT 
    @Year = 2020,
    @Month = 9,
    @TableName = CONCAT( 'Tbl_Billing_Sheet_', @Month , '_',  @Year );

SET @Query = 'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' 
SET 
    [1] = RAN.[1] 
FROM ' + @TableName +' SI 
INNER JOIN Stg_Billing_Sheet RAN 
    ON SI.Associate_ID = RAN.Associate_ID;';

PRINT @Query;
```

`PRINT` displays:

```
UPDATE Tbl_Billing_Sheet_9_2020 
SET 
    [1] = RAN.[1] 
FROM Tbl_Billing_Sheet_9_2020 SI 
INNER JOIN Stg_Billing_Sheet RAN 
    ON SI.Associate_ID = RAN.Associate_ID;
```

Larnu makes a good argument about your design that you should look into. However, this should answer your immediate question.